# React native build failed on `ios` when `react-native run-ios`

Tags: react-native

I am getting this when I am trying to run app on `ios` simulator. can any one guide me what is reason/solution for this issue.

The following build commands failed:

> CompileC /Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/eattog-dfbqbeyhmbgzhfcodvhlcaqjxepf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/P
> ods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactCommon.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/RCTTurboModuleManager.o
> /Users/xxx/Documents/React-Native-Projects/eattog/node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/turbomodule/core/platform/ios/RCTTurboModuleManager.mm normal x86_64 objective-c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

just insert in the end of your Podfile:

```
post_install do |installer|
  ## Fix for XCode 12.5
      find_and_replace("../node_modules/react-native/React/CxxBridge/RCTCxxBridge.mm",
      "_initializeModules:(NSArray<id<RCTBridgeModule>> *)modules", "_initializeModules:(NSArray<Class> *)modules")
      find_and_replace("../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/turbomodule/core/platform/ios/RCTTurboModuleManager.mm",
      "RCTBridgeModuleNameForClass(module))", "RCTBridgeModuleNameForClass(Class(module)))")
  end

def find_and_replace(dir, findstr, replacestr)
  Dir[dir].each do |name|
      text = File.read(name)
      replace = text.gsub(findstr,replacestr)
      if text != replace
          puts "Fix: " + name
          File.open(name, "w") { |file| file.puts replace }
          STDOUT.flush
      end
  end
  Dir[dir + '*/'].each(&method(:find_and_replace))
end
```